# How to make this loop? Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, eigenvalue

For example: I have first vektor **x1**:

```
 x1=[4.8809    0.0034
 4.3352    0.0080
 3.3940    0.0119]
```

and second vector **x2**:

```
 x2=[2.1531    0.0147
 0.7522    0.0162
-0.6510    0.0162]
```

This steps I would like to make as a loop:

1) first row of matrix Z

```
 z1=x1(1,:)
```

2) second row of matrix Z

```
 z2=x2(1,:)
```

3) matrix Z

```
 Z=[z1;z2]
```

4) eigenvalues ​​of matrix Z

```
 e=eig(Z)
```

5) make a vector from eigenvalues **v**

```
 v= [e(1) , e(2) , ...]
```

and the same steps for z1=x1(2,:) and so on... And result is vector **v** with eigenvalues of matrix **Z**.

I don't know how to make it, thank you for your answers, I hope this is clear ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close to the solution.

```
%preallocate v with a zero-array
v=zeros(size(x1))';
for idx=1:size(x1,1)
  %replace the 1 with an index
  z1=x1(idx,:);
  z2=x2(idx,:);
  Z=[z1;z2];
  e=eig(Z);
  %select the right column
  v(:,idx)=e;
end
```

Comment: Thank you, really help me with matrices like 2x1500 etc. ;)

Comment: And if I need only vector v(size(1,n)) instead of matrix v(size(2,n)), can you help me?

Comment: Change `e` to be a scalar instead of a vector. No idea what the intended output is.

Comment: I mean, you made v(size(2x3)), exactly: 
 v =
    [4.8824    4.3366    3.3917
    0.0132    0.0148    0.0185] 
And I would like to make v(size(1x6)), like: 
 v = [4.8824        
    0.0132
    4.3366
    0.0148
    3.3917
    0.0185]

Comment: Take a look at `reshape`

Comment: thank you, but I need to make it in the loop the vector v looking like after reshape